# Cannot install some packages on Xamarin Forms project (netstandard2.0)

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, .net-standard

I am trying to add some packages and I am getting the same error all the time. Below is the error when installing Google Ads:

> Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite 60.1142.1 is not
>   compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package
>   Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite 60.1142.1 supports: monoandroid80
>   (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.0)

I am getting the same if I try to install Compat packages.

- Visual Studio for Mac 7.5.2
- Project Target Framework: .NET Standard 2.0
- Android Target Framework: Android 8.1 (Oreo)
- Android Manifest sdks: android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27"

Can anybody give me some advice as I have been changing some parameters and trying to install other versions of the packages (which should work) but I am getting alway the same problem.

Should that package (google ads) be installed only in the Android project or in the main project as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices

Is designed only for Android projects. Don't add it to your PCL or iOS project. Only add it to your Android Project.

Comment: I tried to install in PCL project and wasted 1hr. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

It is android platform specific lib, so it must be only in Droid project

Comment: I tried to install in PCL project and wasted 1hr. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Remove any "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.*" packages.
2. Clean solution
3. Add latest "Xamarin.GooglePlayServices" package
4. Restart VS
5. Clean Solution
6. Rebuild
7. Run